# Programming Language for both JVM and .NET Runtime

Tags: java, c#, .net, clojure, jvm

I know that Clojure is released for JVM and .NET (CLR).
Is there any programming language that runs both on JVM and on .NET (CLR).
I think it's nice if I can write a program once and run it both on JVM and .NET.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a nitpick: _...Write a program once..._ It is very common for programs to use external libraries - jar or dll downloaded from internet. If your program uses such a dependency, then running across platforms will not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I could find the followings by using Google Search:

1. Ć programming language http://cito.sourceforge.net/

cito automatically translates the Ć programming language to C, Java, C#, JavaScript, ActionScript, Perl and D. Ć is a new language, aimed at crafting portable programming libraries, with syntax akin to C#. The translated code is lightweight (no virtual machine, emulation nor large runtime), human-readable and fits well the target language (including naming conventions and documentation comments).

2. Haxe https://haxe.org/

Code written in the Haxe language can be source-to-source compiled into ActionScript 3, JavaScript, Java, C++, C#, PHP, Python, Lua and Node.js. Haxe can also directly compile SWF and Neko bytecode.

3. Fantom http://fantom-lang.org/

Fantom is an elegant open source, object-oriented, software language that runs on the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).
Designed to be portable, Fantom also compiles to Javascript, and even runs on the .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR)!

4. Onelang

https://github.com/koczkatamas/onelang

https://ide.onelang.io/

Typescript ⇒ C++, C#, Go, Java, JavaScript, Perl, PHP, Python, 
Ruby, Swift

Answer (score 0):

1. JTransc

This is slightly different from what I asked.

However, with this, you could write code in Java and convert to C# etc:

https://www.kotlinresources.com/library/jtransc/

https://github.com/jtransc/jtransc

Convert your Java, Kotlin and Scala code into JavaScript, C++, D, C#, PHP, AS3, Dart and Haxe and run it everywhere. Also use JVM code in your favourite language as a library.

JTransc (Java Trans Compiler) is an AOT (ahead of time compiler) that compiles .class and .jar files into a target programming language / executable bundling all the required dependencies in a single file or folder, without requiring a jitter or an external runtime.

At the beginning it generated as3 and javascript, but right now there are several targets: Javascript, Haxe, C++, and D. Haxe itself allow to target several other languages: JS, AS3, C++, C#, Java, PHP and Python. This in turn allows running the program on different platforms such as desktop, browsers and mobile.

---

2. XMLVM (Bytecode to bytecode converter)

http://www.xmlvm.org/overview/

XMLVM serves as an umbrella for several projects. For all projects, a Java class file or a .NET executable is first translated to an XML-document. Based on the XML-document generated by the front-end, various transformations are possible. The first transformation cross-compiles from .NET to JVM byte code. Another transformation enables Java or .NET applications to be cross-compiled to JavaScript so that they can run as AJAX applications in any browser. Yet another transformation allows to cross-compile a Java program to Objective-C to create a native iPhone application.